# How to fetch WP_User_Query with multiple role arguments

Tags: wordpress

I have two user role

1) vendor 2)freevendor

Here i am trying to fetch user by there user role `vendor` and `freevendor` with the bellow code but query is fetching only `freevendor`.

```
$vendor_total_args = array (
    'role' => 'vendor',
    'role' => 'freevendor',
   'orderby'            => $orderby,
  'order'               => $order,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'pv_merchant__experiance_dropdwon',
            'value'   => $_POST[ 'pv_merchant__experiance_dropdwon1' ],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'pv_merchant_specialization',
            'value'   => $_POST[ 'pv_merchant__experiance_dropdwon2' ],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
```

So how can i fetch multiple user role  `vendor` and `freevendor` using above snippet code.

Comment: You would have to run this twice and merge the results.

Comment: what i need to run this two time separately like  $vendor_total_args1 and $vendor_total_args2 then merge some thing like this array_merge($vendor_total_args1 , $vendor_total_args2 );

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just wait few more days ... for WordPress 4.4 (scheduled early December)

Then you can just use the new attribute:

```
'role__in' => array( 'vendor', 'freevendor' );
```

of the `WP_User_Query` class.

Note there's also the 'role__not_in' attribute to exclude multiple user roles.

Here's the core enhancement [ticket #22212](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22212), that was resolved just recently.

Comment: If you want to test it before WordPress 4.4. is out, you could check out the beta version (but don't do that for a live install). @SanjayNakate

Answer (score 0):

The solution from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39315/get-multiple-roles-with-get-users seems to do what you want:

```
global $wpdb;
$blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => $wpdb->get_blog_prefix( $blog_id ) . 'capabilities',
            'value' => 'role_1',
            'compare' => 'like'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => $wpdb->get_blog_prefix( $blog_id ) . 'capabilities',
            'value' => 'role_2',
            'compare' => 'like'
        )
    )
) );
```

The trick is to get the meta query working with your existing query considering one is "and" and the other is "or". I haven't tested this but it should work:

```
global $wpdb;
$blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array(
    'orderby'  => $orderby,
    'order'    => $order,
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => $wpdb->get_blog_prefix( $blog_id ) . 'capabilities',
            'value' => 'vendor',
            'compare' => 'like'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => $wpdb->get_blog_prefix( $blog_id ) . 'capabilities',
            'value' => 'freevendor',
            'compare' => 'like'
        )
        array(
            'key' => 'genre',
            'value' => $searchvalue,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'pv_merchant__experiance_dropdwon',
        'value'   => $_POST[ 'pv_merchant__experiance_dropdwon1' ],
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key'     => 'pv_merchant_specialization',
        'value'   => $_POST[ 'pv_merchant__experiance_dropdwon2' ],
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
));
```